# Node.js spawn: console.log not logging twice and process.stdin.on('data',callback) not executing

Tags: javascript, node.js, spawn

I have three questions about the code below. Firstly, why wouldn't line A show up on the output in terminal. Right now it seems that line B is being logged while line A is not. Secondly, before the 4000 millisecond mark I tried to type something on the keyboard and expected the chunk of code at C would end the process. However, it kept writing out strings until it reached 4 seconds. When I tried to run alwaysTalking.js on its own my keyboard interruption would actually end the program. Why would it not work here? Lastly, what is line D doing? Is it passing the spawn function to the variable spawn? Is var spawn then an object of the spawn function/class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

alwaysTalking.js:

```
var sayings = [
"You may delay, but time will not.",
"Tell me and I forget. Teach me and I remember. Involve me and I learn.",
"It takes many good deeds to build a good reputation, and only one bad one to lose it.",
"Early to bed and early to rise makes a man healthy, wealthy and wise.",
"By failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail.",
"An investment in knowledge pays the best interest.",
"Well done is better than well said."
];

var interval = setInterval(function() {
var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * sayings.length);
console.log(` ${sayings[i]} \n`);       //line A
}, 1000);

process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {                          //C
console.log(`STDIN Data Recieved -> ${data.toString().trim()}`);   //C
clearInterval(interval);                                           //C
process.exit();                                                    //C
});                                                                //C
```

spawn.js:

```
var spawn = require("child_process").spawn;           //line D
var cp = spawn("node", ["alwaysTalking"]);

cp.stdout.on("data", function(data) {
console.log(`STDOUT: ${data.toString()}`);   //line B
});

cp.on("close", function() {
console.log("Child Process has ended");
process.exit();
});
setTimeout(function() {
cp.stdin.write("stop");
}, 4000);
```

On terminal:

```
$node spawn
STDOUT: abcde You may delay, but time will not. 


STDOUT: abcde Tell me and I forget. Teach me and I remember. Involve me and I learn. 


STDOUT: abcde By failing to prepare, you are preparing to fail. 


STDOUT: STDIN Data Recieved -> stop

Child Process has ended
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing stdin to the child process. You would need to:

```
process.stdin.pipe(cp.stdin);
```

Comment: Could you explain what this thing does?

Comment: It just copies(pipes) any input from the parent's stdin to the child's stdin, otherwise the parent keeps its stdin and it's child's stdin separate.